# React dropzone uploader custom file icon in upload preview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone.js, react-dropzone

I have been using React-Dropzone-uploader. I am wondering if there is any way to change the file icon(custom file icon) in the preview container?. without writing a custom Preview component?
I have checked the documentation and could not find any props to pass in the file icons.

https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/customization.

please let me know your thoughts and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

you can look into [Previews](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/typescript) parameter . maybe you log this param you can see the icon.
but if you can't see any, you must css that file